# mysql - how to sum the count of 2 different elements from the same table and column and show it as one?

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join, case

I have a library with different types of Literary genres, i gotta show it as one, some very similar to the others, so ive been asked to reduce the table size by summing the amount and porcentage from some genres to the similar ones, for example:

AutoBiography must be summarized with Biography, Adventure with Action, Romance with romantic commedy.

Check The fiddle example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df7c87/9

i need to display it as the example below:

```
╔════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ Literary_Genre ║ Day_Amount ║ Day_Porc ║ Yesterday_Amount ║ Yesterday_Porc ║ Month_Amount ║ Month_Porc ║
╠════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Biography      ║ 4          ║ 28,56    ║ 2                ║ 31             ║ 27           ║ 35.9       ║
╠════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ romance        ║ 6          ║ 42,84    ║ 1                ║ 22,6           ║ 56           ║ 61,1       ║
╠════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Action         ║ 1          ║ 7,14     ║ 4                ║ 28,56          ║ 38           ║ 45.1       ║
╚════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

Basically i need to sum the amount of Action+adventure and display it as Adventure Considering the time intervals, and do the same thing for Autobiography+biography and romantic comedy+romance.

**ps**: The porcentage numbers are random as i generated them without calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select
    case Literary_Genre 
        when 'Autobiography' then 'Biography'
        when 'romantic comedy' then 'romance'
        when 'Adventure' then 'Action'
        else Literary_Genre 
    end Real_Literary_Genre,
    sum(Day_Amount) Day_Amount,
    sum(Day_Porc) Day_Porc,
    sum(Yesterday_Amount) Yesterday_Amount,
    sum(Yesterday_Porc) Yesterday_Porc,
    sum(Month_Amount) Month_Amount
    sum(Month_Porc) Month_Porc
from mytable t
group by Real_Literary_Genre
```

If you have a large number of categories to map, you would be better off creating a table to store this information:

```
original_genre    | real_genre
----------------- | ----------------
Autobiography     | Biography
romantic comedy   | romance
Adventure         | Action
```

You can then bring it in with a `left join`:

```
select
    coalesce(m.real_genre, t.Literary_Genre) New_Literary_Genre,
    sum(Day_Amount) Day_Amount,
    sum(Day_Porc) Day_Porc,
    sum(Yesterday_Amount) Yesterday_Amount,
    sum(Yesterday_Porc) Yesterday_Porc,
    sum(Month_Amount) Month_Amount
    sum(Month_Porc) Month_Porc
from mytable t
left join mymapping m on m.original_genre = t.Literary_Genre
group by New_Literary_Genre
```

Comment: the table idea is a real nice one, the problem is i do not have access to the database structure to do this kinda of change. But thanks! You Answer is really Helpful!